# jQuery - Using a checkbox to fade in and out a div

Tags: jquery

I want to use a checkbox to fade in and out a div, but im not sure how to go about it, when you check the box it fades in the div and when you de-select the checkbox it fades it out.

The code i have is as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="trending" id="trending" />

<div id="trendingdisplay">
    <!-- my div content goes in here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/WfMCp/1/

That's just one line, you can use the `fadeToggle()` method

```
$('#trendingdisplay').hide();//hide on load

$('#trending').click(function(){
    $('#trendingdisplay').fadeToggle();
})
```

Comment: That works, except, when the form loads the checkbox will be unchecked, which means that the div should not be there ... it will only appear when the checkbox is ticked.

Comment: @BigJobbies hidden via JS. Makes it more useable

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method:

```
$('#trending').click(function() {
    $('#trendingdisplay').toggle('slow');
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b7aBW/).

Comment: That works, except, when the form loads the checkbox will be unchecked, which means that the div should not be there ... it will only appear when the checkbox is ticked.

Comment: @BigJobbies, in this case you could apply it a CSS class with `display: none;` in order to hide it initially.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#trending').click(function(){
    if($('#trending').is(':checked')) {
        $('#trendingdisplay').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('#trendingdisplay').fadeOut('slow');   
    }
});
```

Comment: a better option would be `if(this.checked)`